# Who else would alter session cookie aside from SessionIDManager in ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms

We are using ASP.NET C# WebForms v 3.5 and we have a custom class that implements ISessionIDManager. Inside our class we have 2 methods that are used for encryption - Encrypt and Decrypt.

The problem is somehow our sessions is being altered by something else. In other words we are getting another value written to the cookie at some point of time during the time user navigates between pages.

When I see the method Encrypt is used last time, it writes the values I would expect to the cookie. Next time the Decrypt is used on the value picked up from the cookie on the next page, it reads in absolutely different data... who could have updated that same cookie and where? It's not our code, so is there anything in the .NET framework that I should be looking at?

Comment: Try changing the name of the cookie in the exact spots you write content to it, and see whether the strange code is getting written to it.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, found it.

Apparently, this same custom class that was implementing ISessionIDManager interface was setting the session cookie in 2 places, and one was using different value encryption technique than the other... oh legacy code...

Thanks for help :)